# Custom YouTrack Workflow 6.0: Can't change 'New Issue' Visibile To

Tags: youtrack

I have a custom WorkFlow that I've built in the Workflow editor. Uploaded it, and assigned it to a project.

When a new Issue is created in that Project, I'm expecting the Visiblity To, to change from {All Users} to {Front End Support}

I have other custom workflows assigned, that are working, so this doesn't have to do with the workflow being added, or assigned to the project.

Here is my workflow, and I've tried a bunch of variations on permittedGroup with, and without the "issue." prefix. None seem to matter.

```
rule Change PermittedGroup to Support

when permittedGroup == {All Users} {
  issue.permittedGroup = {Front End Support}
}
```

This [Sample Workflow](https://github.com/JetBrains/youtrack-workflows/tree/master/Default%20Visibility%20Group), seems to be doing the same thing, though maybe it's old and not compatible with 6.0? [And This](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-4328#tab=Linked%20Issues) talks aboue a 'Visible To' command, but I can't find that anywhere.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fugre this out by testing for the name being blank.

I found this by debugging with messages.

```
when permittedGroup.name != "anything" { 
  message(permittedGroup.name); 
}
```

With this I found out that {All Users} visibility is actually blank. And then my final working code is

```
when permittedGroup.name.trim(mode: nullToEmpty) || permittedGroup.becomes({All Users}) { 
  permittedGroup = {Front End Support}; 

  message("Support Visibility Must be limited to Front End Support or a Customer Team Project"); 
}
```